# PyZMQ - How to terminate a Context if no connection was made?

Tags: tcp, zeromq, pyzmq

I've been trying to figure out how to close a `Context`-instance (or if I even need to) when my socket hasn't yet connected to a bound address.  Here's my demo code:

```
import zmq
import json

data = {}
data['key'] = 'value'
json_data = json.dumps(data)

context = zmq.Context.instance()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5555")

socket.send_json(data)
socket.close()

print("I get here!")

context.term()
```

My expected behavior is that this ends fine.  My actual behavior is that **`context.term()`** blocks with no way to ^C out.  It prints out "I get here!" before it stops, btw.

EDIT Incorporating the chosen answer's solution, this works:

```
import zmq
import json

data = {}
data['key'] = 'value'
json_data = json.dumps(data)

context = zmq.Context.instance()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.LINGER, 100)
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5555")

socket.send_json(data)
socket.close()

print("I get here!")

context.term()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, this is The Desired behaviour. Why?

ZeroMQ uses **`Context`**-instance as an autonomous battlefield unit. It has its own resources and operates in as many IO-threads, as performance tweaking had imperatively required to spawn.

As these resources allocations and transport-related infrastructure is "expensive", the **`.term()`**-instance method takes due care, not to damage toys, that still wait inside IN/OUT-queues, before got delivered. Did I mention both the infrastructure-setup & maintenance plus the message-delivery mechanisms are asynchronous and do not take place, the less are granted to be completed upon request? No, they operate "separately" under the `Context()`-instance hood, in a best-effort fashion, having a **Zen-of-Zero** ( incl. a Zero-"warranty" ) inside the design-DNA...

Your code has put a message already "there", so there is a gold-egg, that the `.term()`-call tries not to damage, before finally killing the `Context`-instance.

This behaviour is indeed **The Desired behaviour** and one can change it for cases, where due design care was taken otherwise:

```
import zmq
import json

print( "Run against ZeroMQ native-API[{0:}]". format( zmq.pyzmq_version_info() ) )    

pass;    aLocalCONTEXT = zmq.Context.instance()
socket = aLocalCONTEXT.socket( zmq.REQ ); socket.connect( "tcp://localhost:5555" )

print( "<aSocket> has LINGER == [{0:}]". format( socket.getsockopt( zmq.LINGER ) )

socket.send_json( json.dumps( { 'key': 'value' } ) ) # MOV. data into Context()
socket.close(); print( "I get here!" )               # N/P to .close() socket


# /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ BUT!

aLocalCONTEXT.term()                                 # THE HELL OPENS HERE,
#                                                    # GIVEN LINGER WAS -1
#                                                    # AS .term()-method
#                                                    # MUST WAIT UNTIL ALL MSGs
#                                                    # KNOWN TO BE IN-FLIGHT
#                                                    # GET INDEED DELIVERED, OUCH
```

Even though newer native ZeroMQ API-versions ( 4.2+ ) promise to have set `zmq.LINGER` default value other than originally injected **`-1`** `== WAIT INDETERMINANTLY TILL DELIVERED, IF NOT FOREVER IN CASE NO PEERS ARE OUT THERE`

so a due design-side care is indeed a sign of a fair engineering practice :o)

Comment: Thank you!  Linger is exactly what I needed for this!